# JSON deserialization to object, with partial dynamic properties

Tags: c#, json

I am calling a rest service, and the service returns JSON content.  Most of the content has a predefined structure, but some of the content is dynamic based on parameters that were passed to the rest service.
Once I get the response back from the rest service, I want to deserialize to an object so I can easily use the data.  I am currently using the DataContractJsonSerializer to do that.

```
/// <summary>
/// Deserialize JSON formatted string to an object of a specified type
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">Object type to deserialize</typeparam>
/// <param name="sJSON">JSON formatted string to deserialize</param>
/// <returns>Returns an instance of an object</returns>
public static T FromJSON<T>(this string sJSON) where T : new()
{
    T oValue;

    using (System.IO.MemoryStream strJSON = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
    {
        using (System.IO.StreamWriter swJSON = new System.IO.StreamWriter(strJSON))
        {
            swJSON.Write(sJSON);
            swJSON.Flush();

            strJSON.Seek(0, System.IO.SeekOrigin.Begin);

            System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));
            oValue = (T)ser.ReadObject(strJSON);

            return oValue;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is an example of the rest service response:

```
{
    "entities" : [{
            "type" : "mytest",
            "properties" : {
                "Active" : true,
                "Category" : "10732",
                "Description" : "test test test",
                "LastUpdateTime" : 1446676525195,
                "Id" : "12655"
            }
        }
    ],
    "metadata" : {
        "status" : "OK",
        "count" : 0
    }
}
```

The object will always have an "entities" and "metadata" property, the metadata will always have a "status" and "count" property, and the entities will always be an array, and each item in the array will have a "type" and "properties" property.  The dynamic nature comes into play for the properties object, which will contain properties entirely based on what was passed into the rest service.

This is the class definition, I've been using to deserialize the json string into objects.  But I'm unsure how I can make the properties portion dynamic.  Even if I could end up with dictionary of name values that would be workable.  Is this possible, ideally without the requirement of 3rd party json libraries?

```
[DataContract]
public class Response
{
    [DataMember(
    public Entity[] entities { get; set; }

    [DataMember(
    public MetaData metadata { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class Entity
{
    [DataMember(
    public string type { get; set; }  

    [DataMember()]
    public Properties properties { get; set; }
}


[DataContract]
public class Properties
{
     //How do I make this part dynamic?
}

[DataContract]
public class MetaData
{
    [DataContract]
    public enum Status
    {
        [EnumMember]
        OK,

        [EnumMember]
        FAILED
    }

    public Status CompletionStatus { get; set; }

    [DataMember()]
    public string status
    {
        get
        {
            return this.CompletionStatus.ToString();
        }
        set
        {
            this.CompletionStatus = (Status)Enum.Parse(typeof(Status), value);
        }
    }

    [DataMember()]
    public int count{ get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Make the properties a `Dictionary<string, object>`

Comment: @Rob - that doesn't seem to work.  The "Properties" property always has a count of 0.

Comment: had a closer look at it - you also need to configure the serializer to properly serialize JSON objects/dictionaries - see answer posted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your property to this:

```
[DataMember]
public Dictionary<string, object> properties { get; set; }
```

And then you need to configure the serializer:

```
var ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T), new DataContractJsonSerializerSettings {
    UseSimpleDictionaryFormat = true 
});
```

Comment: Alternatively if you use JSON.net for serialisation it'll handle it automatically

Comment: Oh that's great!  Way better than the approach I took, which was to create a class implementing ISerializable then use the Constructor(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context);

Comment: This is the correct answer because most of the object has a fixed structure and only the properties is dynamic. The other answers make the whole object dynamic.

Answer (score 1):

So i placed part of your code into a console app and played around with it a bit and what you want to use is called a dynamic type.

Here was my code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
        string test = @" [{
        ""type"" : ""mytest"",
        ""properties"" : {
            ""Active"" : true,
            ""Category"" : ""10732"",
            ""Description"" : ""test test test"",
            ""LastUpdateTime"" : 1446676525195,
            ""Id"" : ""12655""
        }
    },
{
        ""type"" : ""mytest1"",
        ""properties"" : {
            ""Active"" : true,
            ""Category"" : ""10731232"",
            ""Description"" : ""test test1 test"",
            ""LastUpdateTime"" : 144195,
            ""Id"" : ""126155""
        }
    }
]";
        List<Entity> entities = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Entity>>(test);
        foreach (Entity e in entities)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.properties.Active);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Here is my class:

```
public class Entity
    {
         public string type { get; set; }
        public dynamic properties { get; set; }
    }
```

So since properties is dynamic it gets the data from your JSon and decides what its structure needs to looks like. I used Newtsoft to deserialize, but the concept should stay the same. 
Also be careful since it is dynamic some types like boolean might not transfer over correctly, so make sure when you get it in C# to get their correct types matched